# How to proportionally decrease positive and negative numbers

Tags: php, algorithm, algebra

I have two variables:

`$points - could be positive or negative`
`$time_elapsed -is always positive`

I'm trying to proportionally decrease `$points` based on `$time_elapsed`. I can't use subtraction because it's not "proportional" the way I need it. I need something similar to division, but that always decreases $points (division increases the number if it's negative) so that I get the following result:

```
$points = -12;
$time_elapsed = 4;
$points/time_elapsed = -48;

$points = 12;
$time_elapsed = 4;
$points/time_elapsed = 3;
```

I cannot use abs() because it would return -3 when points is -12, when really I need it to return -48 (I always need something that is $time_elapsed times smaller than $points).
I cannot use if conditions or anything similar. Is this even possible?

Comment: where is $time_elapsed? what is its relation with $point?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: If you have a table of values for the three variables you can use a numeric method to get an approximate relation (equation) between them.

Comment: why not use conditional operator?

Comment: Maybe it's a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract sign bit and use it to avoid conditional operators (while this restriction is weird idea):

```
 $sgn = ($points >> 31) & 1  //(for 32-bit variables)
 return   $points * $sgn * $time + $points * (1 - $sgn) / $time

 //returns $points * $time for negative and $points / $time for positive
```

Comment: It's the same as using abs(). For $points = -12 and $time = 4 it returns -3 instead of -48, thus increasing $points instead of decreasing it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. No conditionals!

[Fiddle here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e283ead137d63b80de92d80a7e236153b5caf30e)

```
function getPoints($points, $time_elapsed)
{
    $is_positive = $points > 0;

    $converters = [
        true => function($points, $time_elapsed) {
            return $points / $time_elapsed;
        },
        false => function($points, $time_elapsed) {
            return $points * $time_elapsed;
        }
    ];

    return $converters[$is_positive]($points, $time_elapsed);
}

echo getPoints(-12, 4), PHP_EOL;
echo getPoints(12, 4), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: This `$points > 0` actually is an if condition, even if there's no if involved directly.

Comment: @MichaelZukowski Technically it's an expression; if they can use `/`, they can use `>`.